# How to select rows from a table parameter into a cursor

Tags: oracle

I would like to pass a table parameter to an Oracle stored procedure and return a cursor with the table values and some extra data i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EVENTPACKAGE AS
  TYPE T_STRING_TAB IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(260) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
END;

create or replace
procedure spTest(eventids in EVENTPACKAGE.T_STRING_TAB, p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
begin

  open p_cursor for 
    select * from
    (
      select *, 'test1', 'test2' from eventids
    );

end;
```

So if the `eventids` contained 3 strings called "First", "Second" and "Third" the procedure would return:

```
"First", "test1", "test2"
"Second", "test1", "test2"
"Third", "test1", "test2"
```

The parameter is a table so why won't this work?

Comment: "why won't this work" - you haven't said what happens, what errors you get, etc. Usually you need a schema-level collection (i.e. `create type ...`) not a PL/SQL collection to be able to use the collection in a query. The version of Oracle you are using may make a difference. Your inner query isn't prefixing the `*` with the table name/alias. It's hard to tell which bit you are asking about though.

Comment: The error is: Error(7,19): PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item. The create type must be in a package as I need to call this sp from c# code.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Just with the table prefix, this works in 11.2.0.4. (Without a `table()` call...) In 11.2.0.2 you do need the `table()`, but then that throws ORA-22905, so you need a schema-level type. In 12c+ it works with the `table()` call (as shown in Chris' answer). So - the version you are using matters.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.

Comment: Please note that I cannot create a schema level type with an index i.e. create or replace
TYPE T_STRING_TAB IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(260) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER. I get the error: Error(2,22): PLS-00355: use of pl/sql table not allowed in this context

Comment: [No](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8001.htm), it would have to be a [varray](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF51007) or [nested table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF51008); but do you need it to be indexed? Also, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57511912/edit) to add information, including the version and the errors.

Comment: By *"with an index"* you mean the `index by` syntax of a PL/SQL (non-SQL) associative array?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

- You need to alias the inner * if you also want to return other expressions
- To select from a PL/SQL array, you need to use the table() operator

Which gives:

```
var cur refcursor;

create or replace package eventpackage as
  type t_string_tab is table of varchar2(20) 
    index by pls_integer;

  string_tab t_string_tab;
end;
/

begin
  eventpackage.string_tab(1) := 'First';
  eventpackage.string_tab(2) := 'Second';
  eventpackage.string_tab(3) := 'Third';

  open :cur for 
    select * from (
      select t.*, 'test1', 'test2' 
      from   table ( 
        eventpackage.string_tab
      ) t
    );

end;
/

print :cur;

Result Sequence      'TEST 'TEST
-------------------- ----- -----
First                test1 test2
Second               test1 test2
Third                test1 test2
```